# Rails 4 + Merit + Devise: set a badge for user after registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, merit-gem

I have a trouble at this situation. I followed [this manual](https://github.com/tute/merit/wiki/How-to-grant-badges-on-user-registration-using-Devise), but it don't helped me.

Here's my files:

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
```

merit.rb:

```
Merit.setup do |config|
  config.checks_on_each_request = true
end

Merit::Badge.create!(
  id: 1,
  name: 'just-registered',
  description: 'Badge for register'
)
```

badge_rules.rb

```
module Merit
  class BadgeRules
    include Merit::BadgeRulesMethods

    def initialize
      grant_on 'registrations#create', badge: 'just-registered', model_name: 'User'
    end
  end
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = build_resource
  super
end
```

And if make sense - when user is registered, to merit_actions table added a new record with `target_model = 'registrations', not 'users'`

Can someone tell me, what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to add `to: :action_user` in the registrations#create grant rule

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior, `merit_actions` is internal to the gem and saves `controller_path` as it's `target_model` attribute. It is confusing, but it shouldn't affect your application. Is the badge being granted?

Comment: Its working if we use `to: :action_user` with the rule defined above ,but what if we are using devise ` confirmable` functionality.It not creating badge in that case

Comment: With comfirmable, it's maybe another endpoint than `registrations#create` that you should target. I'd need to see the app to provide more help.